# Filtering text from string

Tags: c#

I have it now like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
   public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Consider making this configurable
            const string sourceFile = "test2.txt";
            const string pattern = "http://10.123.9.66:80";
            //var FirstSeparatorLastNameExact = new[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
            //var SecondSeparatorLastNameExact = new[] { "qxq)" };

            string[] FirstSeparator = new string[] { "nosyn_name_last_exact:(qxq" };
            string[] SecondSeparator = new string[] { "qxq)" };

            string[] FirstSeperatorFirstName = new string[] {"nosyn_name_first_exact:(qxq"};
            string[] secondSeperatorFirstName = new string[]{"qxq)"};



            Regex re = new Regex("^(http|https)://");
            HttpWebResponse response;

           // var webClient = new WebClient();
            var times = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>();
            var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            //Add header so if headers are tracked, it will show it is your application rather than something ambiguous
            //webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Response-Tester-Client");

            var urlList = new List<string>();

            //Loop through the lines in the file to get the urls 
            try
            {
                stopwatch.Start();
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFile))
                {

                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var urNewList = new List<string>();
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        //line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(pattern));
                        //line.Split("\t");
                        var columns = line.Split('\t');
                        //var result = line.Split(Seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Split(')')[0];
                        if (columns[2] == "R")
                        {
                            var url = columns[4] + "?" + columns[5];
                            urlList.Add(url);
                            Thread.Sleep(250);
                        }
                        //if (line.Contains(result))
                        //{
                            //MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, lastName);
                            //foreach (string lines in File.ReadLines(sourceFile))
                            //{

                                //var LastNameSearch = line.Split(FirstSeparatorLastNameExact, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                                //var resultLastNameSearch = LastNameSearch.Split(FirstSeparatorLastNameExact, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];


                                //var temp = line.Split(FirstSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
                                //var result2 = temp.Split(SecondSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                                //Console.WriteLine(result2);

                        string[] result = line.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        if (result.Length > 2)
                        {
                            string[] inner = result[1].Split(')');
                            if (inner.Length > 1)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(inner[0]);
                                Console.WriteLine(result);
                            }
                        }


                        //var split = line.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        //if (split.Length > 1)
                        //{
                        //    Console.WriteLine(split[1].Split(')')[0]);
                        //   // Console.WriteLine(split);
                        //}


                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to access the source file at {0}", sourceFile);
            }
            finally
            {
                //Stop, record and reset the stopwatch
                stopwatch.Stop();
                times.Add("FileReadTime", stopwatch.Elapsed);
                stopwatch.Reset();
            }

            //Try to connect to each url
            var counter = 1;
            foreach (var url in urlList)
            {
                try
                {
                    stopwatch.Start();

                    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                    {

                        webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Response-Tester-Client");

                       // HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                        request.Method = "POST";

                        //webClient.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occured while attempting to connect to {0}", url);
                }
                finally
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();

                    //We use the counter for a friendlier url as the current ones are unwieldly
                    times.Add("Url " + counter, stopwatch.Elapsed);
                    counter++;

                    stopwatch.Reset();
                }
            }

            //Release the resources for the WebClient 
            //webClient.Dispose();

            //Write the response times

            Console.WriteLine("Url " + "\t\t\t\tLast Name");
            foreach (var key in times.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, times[key].TotalSeconds);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But I still get the error: Index was outside the bounds of the array. So how to change it? And in fact It also has to be remove the qxq. I try it with two string that I declared above

Thank you

Comment: Because your string doesn't have `nosyn_name_first_exact:(qxq` part and there is no second element of `result` array. That's why `Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]` throws exception.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but how to skip the line if there is no nosyn_name_first_exact and then it goes to the second line, because I have a text with more http://..

Comment: ...so test the collection returned by the `Split()` method before you index it.  Make sure it has two or more entries so that the `[1]` index is not out of bounds.  You may want to do the same with the second `Split()` as well to make sure the collection is not empty before trying to `Dump()` the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to fetch a index from an array that do not have that many values (index is out of bounds).

Check if the array is long enough before you try to fetch the index, like:

```
string[] result = test.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if(result.Length > 2) {
  string[] inner = result[1].Split(')');
  if(inner.Length > 1) {
    inner[0].Dump();
  }
}
```

Or check if the string contains the given substring before even trying to split:

```
if(test.Contains("nosyn_name_first_exact:(qxq")) {
  // Split and do whatever.
}
```

Comment: Oke, thank you, but I want to write it to  Console.WriteLine and not Dump

Comment: Adding more code don't really make the problem easier to locate. You have got answers for your initial question, both answers contains the information you need to figure out how to solve the initial problem (question). If you need more help after that, don't edit the question. Either comment followup questions or create a new question if its not a followup.

Answer (score 1):

> how to skip the line if there is no nosyn_name_first_exact

Split your code to not assume there is one. You have:

```
test.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
    .Split(')')[0]
    .Dump();
```

Change it to something like:

```
var split = test.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (split.Length > 1)
{
    split[1].Split(')')[0].Dump();
}
```

You see the same problem can occur within the `if`, repeat if necessary.

Comment: Thank you CodeCaster, but if I want to write it to the console, I try it like this: var split = line.Split(FirstSeperatorFirstName, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                        if (split.Length > 1)
                        {
                            split[1].Split(')')[0].ToString();
                            Console.WriteLine(split);
                        }